# KivyMD TopAppBar mode: "free-center" not working

Tags: kivymd

I'm trying to create a toolbar at the bottom of the screen, with a button of mode "free-center" as displayed in the documentation: https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.1/components/toolbar/index.html

Here is my the toolbar in my .kv file:

```
MDBottomAppBar:
  MDTopAppBar:
    icon: "camera"
    type: "bottom"
    mode: "free-center"
```

The toolbar is displayed, however the button with a camera icon is displayed in the "free-end" position. Setting mode to "center", "free-end", or "end" displays the correct position, however mode: "free-center" doesn't seem to be working.

These are my Kivy-related requirements:

```
Kivy==2.2.0.dev0
kivy-deps.angle==0.3.3
kivy-deps.glew==0.3.1
kivy-deps.gstreamer==0.3.3
kivy-deps.sdl2==0.5.1
Kivy-examples==2.2.0.dev0
Kivy-Garden==0.1.5
kivymd==1.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected in the latest version stable version (v1.1.1 as of writing this). The documentation you linked is for v0.104.0 which is quite old.  Please upgrade your KivyMD to v1.1.1 or later.

```
python -m pip install kivymd --upgrade
```